# Use flags with ARGS in CMD(Dockerfile)

Tags: docker, go, cmd, dockerfile, environment-variables

I'm trying to use args in Dockerfile CMD. I know that we should use ENV in CMD so I've tried to do this but nothing happened in my case.

**kvs** is a bynary file built from Golang application.

My `Dockerfile`:

```yaml
FROM alpine

ARG HOST
ENV HOST_NAME=$HOST

COPY kvs /
COPY *.crt /
COPY *.key /

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["/kvs", "-host", $HOST_NAME]
```

I've tryied:

CMD ["/kvs", "-host", ${HOST_NAME}]

CMD ["/kvs", "-host", $HOST_NAME]

CMD ["/kvs", "-host", "${HOST_NAME}"]

CMD ["/kvs", "-host", "$HOST_NAME"]

CMD ["/kvs", "-host", "echo $HOST_NAME"]

CMD ["/kvs", "-host", "echo ${HOST_NAME}"]

Nothing from above is working!

**Error** is:

```
/bin/sh: [/kvs,: not found
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
CMD /kvs -host=$HOST_NAME
```

Any other ways is not working. I hope that it will help someone.

This is not working:

```
CMD ["/kvs", "-host=$HOST_NAME"]
```